# dbus-daemon - session.conf - windows configuration issue with the noncefile

Tags: ipc, daemon, dbus

I have an issue with running dbus-daemon on Windows 7 platform. I downloaded **dbus 1.4.18** sources and built it using **cmake and visual 2010 compilator**. Then I started dbus-daemon using dbus-launch and it works. After that I tried to connect to the bus using a simple code:

```
DBusConnection* conn;
DBusError err;

dbus_error_init(&err);
conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err);
```

but still I have the same error:

> "Server address of type nonce-tcp was missing argument noncefile"

So I killed dbus-daemon proccess, opened session.conf file and added noncefile path inside  tag like you can see below:

```
<listen>nonce-tcp:noncefile=C:\my_temporary_path</listen>
```

Then and tried to start it once again, but I cannot see a dbus-daemon process on a task list I don't have any error message also though I started dbus-daemon in verbose mode. I tried to add some more parameters like host and port as I found into documentation:

> http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html

But deamon still doesn't work. When I get back to previous setting "nonce-tcp:" everything looks fine.

What did I do wrong?

- %temp% - this is the place where nonce files are created by dbus-daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<listen>nonce-tcp:</listen>` is OK for the *daemon* configuration. IIUC the daemon is supposed to add the `noncefile` parameter when writing out the address that the clients should use. The *client* should look for the address via the mechanism described in http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-types. Sorry, I don't know how that works out on Windows, it looks like consulting the sources of libdbus is necessary.